Using a matrix constant as input for control elements and validity
Given that you have in Microsoft Excel a matrix constant named Values defined as ={"One","Two","Three"}, how can I use the constant in control elements like listbox or combobox or INDIRECT()?
I am well aware that those use cases require a range and not a matrix constant, but is there a way to convert one into the other by built-in means like functions? I would be able to construct or convert ranges in VBA, but I would like to have universal way to achieve this.
I already thought about creating a range from a built-in function with the same dimensions and assigning the values from the matrix constant with encapsulated function calls, but I am not sure, whether this is achievable.
Looking forward to hear any suggestions!
PS: I am not looking for a VBA solution, I want to achieve this with built-in means. And please do not ask me to use a range instead and why I want to use a matrix constant - it is as it is. ;)

Based on the answer to this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31223709/fill-a-listbox-with-an-array-in-vba
you can use Evaluate function to convert Excel matrix constant to vba array and then use it to populate a listbox, for example
Sub Listbox_Things()

'My Listbox is called "Listbox1" and it is located on "Sheet1"
'With the Listbox visible, F8 through this code

    With Sheet1.ListBox1
        .List = Split("1,2,3", ",")
        .Clear
        .List = Array("One", "Two", "Three")
        .Clear
        .List = [Values]  ' here 'Values' is defined in Excel
        .Clear
        .List = Array(1, 2, 3)
        .Clear

        Dim x() As Variant
        x = Array("One", "Two", "Three")

        .List = x
        .Clear
        .List = Application.GetCustomListContents(2)

    End With
End Sub

You cannot use INDIRECT function because it works only for ranges. You can use EVALUATE instead.

Thank you for the code suggestion. I am trying to find a built-in function that delivers a range that could be used to overcome that limitation in Microsoft Excel. And, yes, I know that I could code a universal function that converts a matrix into an array in VBA as well. ;)

I'm afraid that such a function does not exist. There are no abstract ranges, the range must be placed on a specific sheet, at a specific address.

I hoped for something like the .Cells() function in VBA ... I could even live with taking an arbitrary range like A1:A3 and replacing its cell values with the values of the matrix constant - but unfortunately there really does not seem to be any kind of serialization/deserialization function that I could do the dirty trick with. :/
